# Jacobite girl and Catholic Boy (Syro-Malabar) marriage and inter-liturgy (Can we have Syro-Malankara mass in Syro-Malabar church)

Tags: eastern-orthodox, marriage, christianity-in-india, syro-malabar

I was thinking about the marriage between a Syro-Malabar boy and a Jacobite girl.

I know there are norms and rules about marriage between people from both churches and it is allowed. But the girl has a weird request as the boy is Syro-Malabar the wedding will be in a Syro-Malabar rite but in the Syro-Malabar rite in the wedding ceremony, the bride and groom are required to place hands on the holy gospel and take an oath. She is against taking an oath as she claims it is a direct violation of the commandment "Thou shalt not take the name of the Lord thy God in vain". This has quite stirred me as the oath-taking is done by placing hands on the Bible.
To solve this I found a solution to change from Syro-Malabar to Syro-Malankara as in Syro-Malankara it is different and more familiar to the girl and no bible- and oath-taking (correct me if I'm wrong).

But the problem is there is only one Syro-Malankara church nearby and it is far away from the boy's Parish which can create logistical and other problems as both of them have a big family and related issues.
I was wondering if there is any way to conduct a Syro-Malankara rite at the Syro-Malabar church (boy's Parish).

I also would love to know any other potential solutions.
As she was brought up in her faith I cannot force herself to correct it (I don't have the authority). And I want to respect her beliefs also don't want to create a problem.

Would it be a problem if she didn't hold the Bible and take an oath?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Answer (score 1):

Three rites are followed by the respective Catholic communities of Kerala: Latin, Syro Malabar and Syro Malankara. The faithful can attend any Mass said in either of the three rites on Sundays and days of obligation. It has also been a practice that churches belonging to a certain rite are let to be used by other rites on special occasions . As such, it is possible to say Mass in Malankara Catholic rite in a church normally used by Syro Malabar rite. But, you have stated that the girl is  a Jacobite, meaning that she belongs to Orthodox Malankara community which has no allegiance  to the Pope. In that case, permission may have to be sought from higher authorities like the Bishop to conduct a Non- Catholic service in the Catholic church.

> PS: In 1653, a large fraction of St Thomas Christian community of Kerala  split away from Roman Catholicism, the split  attributed to  undue influence   of the Portugese.In 1932, a fraction of the split-away group     reunited with Catholic Church and is known as Syro Malanka Catholics. Those who continue  to have no allegiance to Pope are the Syrian Orthodox Malankara Christians.

Comment: Yes there are laws that attribute to interchurch marriages. And for them it is not customary to take oath by bible and they are unfamiliar with it. Is it a against the 10 commandments to take oath by bible.(3rd commandment)
As for syro-malabar rite the tradition is to take oath by bible.